# How to use type traits to define a partially abstract template base class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, abstract-class, type-traits

I'm working on the following idea:

There exists a generally abstract templated base class with mutiple template parameters. This class defines a contract guaranteeing the presence of certain methods i.e. a method getMax(). This method among others is generally purely virtual. Except there are special cases in which a sensible implementation can be given without the need to implement it manually every time in a derived class. So basically what I'm trying to achive is to (partially) implement the contracted methods already inside the abstract base class if the template arguments allow this.

I made a small example to illustrate the idea. (Note: The example is not perfect, for instance the implementation for std::string is very special and already implicitly forces TSize to be std::size_t)

```
#ifndef ABSTRACTBASE_H
#define ABSTRACTBASE_H

#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

template <typename TSize, typename TVal1, typename TVal2>
class AbstractBase
{
    public:
        AbstractBase(){};
        virtual ~AbstractBase() {};
        virtual TSize getMax() const = 0; // <-- getMax should be generally 
                                          //     purely virtual.

    private:
        TVal1 value1;
        TVal2 value2;
};

//except when TVal1 is an arithmetic type in that case the following definition 
//shall become active.
template <typename TSize, 
          typename TVal1, 
          typename TVal2, 
          typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<TVal1>::value, TSize>::type>
TSize AbstractBase<TSize, TVal1, TVal2>::getMax() const
{
    return std::numeric_limits<TVal1>::max();
}

//... or when TVal1 is a string where this defintion makes sense
template <typename TSize, 
          typename TVal1, 
          typename TVal2, 
          typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<TVal1, std::string>::value, TSize>::type>
TSize AbstractBase<TSize, TVal1, TVal2>::getMax() const
{
    return value1.max_size();
}

//... in all other cases the getMax() method shall stay purely virtual and an 
//appropriate definition must be implemented inside a derived class

#endif //ABSTRACTBASE_H


#include "AbstractBase.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    AbstractBase<int, int, int> arthBase();
    AbstractBase<std::size_t, std::string, long> alphaBase();

    std::cout << arthBase.getMax() << std::endl;
    std::cout << alphaBase.getMax() << std::endl;
}
```

So I guess what is missing here is a method to actually also alter the declaration ov getMax() as virtual, though im not really sure if/how this is possible using type_traits.

Side note: I haven't worked with type traits very much yet. I know about the SFINAE principle behind it, which basically states that if the substitution for a template parameter fails the following code will be excluded from compilation rather than causing an error. What I haven't found out if the type_trait argument responsible for enabling/disabling the method has to be merged into the class template argument list like I did above, or if it is legal/possible to provide the type trait arguments in a seperate template argument list. In this case I *guess* it is impossible because the enable_if statement tests the classes template arguments which have to be declared/valid in this context.

Just in case you use really sophisticated type trait magic a more elaborate comment on that part is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annoying part here is that the string version needs to access a member variable. So one way around that is to put the members in the most base class:

```
template <typename TVal1, typename TVal2>
class Members {
protected:
    TVal1 value1;
    TVal2 value2;
};
```

Just outsource `getMax()` to a different type:

```
// pure case
template <typename TSize, typename TVal1, typename TVal2>
struct VirtualMax : Members<TVal1, TVal2> {
    virtual TSize getMax() const = 0;
};

// integer case
template <typename TSize, typename TVal1, typename TVal2>
struct IntMax : Members<TVal1, TVal2> {
    TVal1 getMax() const { return std::numeric_limits<TVal1>::max(); }
};

// string case
template <typename TSize, typename TVal1, typename TVal2>
struct StringMax : Members<TVal1, TVal2> {
    size_t getMax() const {
        return this->value1.max_size();
    }
};
```

So then we write a type trait:

```
template <typename TSize, typename TVal1, typename TVal2>
using Base_t = std::conditional_t<
    std::is_same<TVal1, std::string>::value,
    StringMax<TSize, TVal1, TVal2>,
    std::conditional_t<
        std::is_arithmetic<TVal1>::value,
        IntMax<TSize, TVal1, TVal2>,
        VirtualMax<TSize, TVal1, TVal2>
        >
    >;
```

And then use that alias:

```
template <typename TSize, typename TVal1, typename TVal2>
class AbstractBase
: Base_t<TSize, TVal1, TVal2>
{ };
```

Comment: Hey Barry thanks for the answer looks like a good solution to me - though I'm still struggling a bit with putting the pieces together to make AbstractBase appear like a single class (hidding all the helper classes/structs). So I thought it might be a good thing to wrap Members, and struct *Max inside the AbstractBase class which obviously can't work since we're using the helpers to define a type Base_t to derive AbstractBase from... any suggestions on how to wrap this in as few headers as possible so it doesn't create a forest of files for one class?

Comment: @norritt If you don't want an unnecessarily complex hierarchy, don't come up with an unnecessarily complex design.

Comment: Didn't want to criticize your proposal. The alternative would be to Copy&Paste the same code to a dozen of derived classes (the ones using arithmetic types) reducing maintainability. If possible I keep my code redundancy down to zero so if I have to do a change I can do it in one place and once place only, so I wouldn't call that unnecessary. The helper class idea is very nice I'm just trying to find a way to hide them in the scope of the project because they are not relevant outside the scope of AbstractBase.

Comment: But the visibility issue asside I keep getting a compiler error with [this](http://pastebin.com/AsSJNkg7) code: In file included from Base.h:4:0, from main.cpp:1: AbstractBase.h:10:24: error: expected type-specifier
 using AbstractBase_t = std::conditional_t...

Answer (score 0):

After some tinkering and thanks to some ideas Barry gave me with his post above I took another shot at the problem myself. While Barrys answer provides a solution to the actual question I'd go and reply to myself to the question with "You don't.". The why Barry and me discussed in the comments:

1. The design gets complex
2. You clutter up your class hierarchy with lots of helper classes and structs that have no relevance for the actual project but exist purely out of architectural reasons to make the method selection based on type traits work.

So the much cleaner shot at this problem would be to keep the "AbstractBase" class purely abstract and combine type traits with inheritance deriving an ArithmeticBase class and a StringBase class using type traits to validate they only take valid template arguments. A solution could look like this:

```
#include <limits>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

#ifndef ABSTRACTBASE_H
#define ABSTRACTBASE_H

template <typename TSize, 
          typename TVal1, 
          typename TVal2>
class AbstractBase {
    public:
        virtual ~AbstractBase() {};
        virtual TSize getMax() const = 0;

    protected:
        TVal1 value1;
        TVal2 value2;
};

#endif //ABSTRACTBASE_H

#ifndef ARITHMETICBASE_H
#define ARITHMETICBASE_H

#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>
#include "AbstractBase.h"

template <typename TSize,
          typename TVal1,
          typename TVal2 = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<TVal1>::value>::type>
class ArithmeticBase : public AbstractBase<TSize, TVal1, TVal2>
{
    public:
        virtual ~ArithmeticBase() {};
        virtual TSize getMax() const { return std::numeric_limits<TVal1>::max(); };
};

#endif //ARITHMETICBASE_H

#ifndef STRINGBASE_H
#define STRINGBASE_H

#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include "AbstractBase.h"

template <typename TSize,
          typename TVal1,
          typename TVal2 = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<TVal1, std::string>::value>::type>
class StringBase : public AbstractBase<TSize, TVal1, TVal2>
{
    public:
        virtual ~StringBase() {};
        virtual TSize getMax() const { return this->value1.max_size(); };
};

#endif //STRINGBASE_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "ArithmeticBase.h"
#include "StringBase.h"
int main()
{
    ArithmeticBase<int, int, int> arthBase;
    StringBase<std::size_t, std::string, long> alphaBase;

    std::cout << arthBase.getMax() << std::endl;
    std::cout << alphaBase.getMax() << std::endl;
}
```